# Android Push Notification for MySQL and PHP

Tags: android, php, mysql, notification

I've done research these past 3 days on how to possibly be notified in realtime for mysql. The issue is MySQL doesn't have that feature available so you have to result to other options like:

- Migrate data to using Cloud Functions with Firebase (FCM)
- Use React to listen for changes
- Angular

Now it all sounds nice to have these options but I don't want to move any of my data to another DB. I enjoy using MySQL and want to keep my data there. I have registered users and keep track of comments, likes, posts etc. I use a custom API that I developed with php to communicate from MySQL to the mobile application.

What are my options that will allow me to keep my data in MySQL while also being able to implement a realtime notification feature that communicates with my android application? (if you can recommend maybe software and the process on how to go about it) Thank you in advanced!

Comment: How is the data getting into MySql? Through some software, I imagine. Can't you edit that to send notifications?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Data is retrieved from the mobile application that the user types in and then sent to my API.php. After all parameters are met and approved then it gets sent to my DB in MySQL where it also retrieves a response in JSON or String.

Comment: Start
1) MobileApplication -> API.php (in cPanel) -> MySQL DB

Response after start
2) MySQL DB -> API.php -> Mobile Application (Android)